# Get inserted colm_ID from table A to used it in table B using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I just want to ask how to get latest inserted ID from table A as an example and use it to enter a record in another table B?

Comment: You can use triggers for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question well, You need to perform two `INSERT` statements within one `Stored Procedure` and use the ID generated from the first statement to use it in the second statement, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

```
create proc yourproc
    (
       -- parameter definitions here
    )
    as
    begin
            insert into Employee
            (FN,LN,Address) 
            values 
            (@FN,@LN,@Address)

    declare @EmployeeID int 
    set @EmployeeID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

            insert into EmpContact
            (Empid, ContactType, ContactNumber) 
            values 
            (@EmployeeID, @ContactType, @ContactNumber) 
    end
```

> SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are
>   generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY
>   returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is
>   not limited to a specific scope.

[SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: This assumes that there is an identity column on the table